# 2D top down character not moving in Unity version 2021.3.20f1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was following this tutorial for a 2D, top down RPG until around the 40 minute mark. I tested the code that was given and the player did not move. There were no errors. Here's the tutorial if required: https://youtu.be/7iYWpzL9GkM

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

// Takes and handles input and movement for a player character
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public float collisionOffset = 0.05f;
    public ContactFilter2D movementFilter;

    Vector2 movementInput;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    List<RaycastHit2D> castCollisions = new List<RaycastHit2D>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        if(movementInput != Vector2.zero){
            int count = rb.Cast(
                movementInput, 
                movementFilter, 
                castCollisions, 
                moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset); 
    
            rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movementInput * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        }
    }

    void OnMove(InputValue movementValue) {
        movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you attach the controller script to the player?

Comment: @Sorceri Yes I did.

Comment: how are you triggering "OnMove"

Comment: @BugFinder I realized I didn't call it, I called it, and it still did not work.

Comment: How are you calling it?

Comment: @BugFinder By putting both functions in void loop(), I just realized I'm an idiot.

Comment: @AtomicUnleashed the input system needs to call it, you cant just call it... so yes, maybe not your greatest choice of the day, but Ive seen worse :)